# What is the grammatical function of "des" in this context?

Tags: grammaire, déterminants

From [a press article](http://bibliobs.nouvelobs.com/la-bibliotheque-de-l-ete/20130724.OBS0850/la-bibliotheque-de-l-ete-gulliver-c-est-pour-les-grandes-personnes.html) in  *Le nouvel Observateur*:

> […] il rencontre entre autres des hommes obsédés par la science,
>    abîmés dans des spéculations abstraites, et qui ont perdu tout contact
>    avec le monde.

In both examples, **des hommes obsédés** and **des spéculations abstraites**, *des* seems to be the English equivalent for the zero article: *obsessed people* and *random speculations*.

Is this **des**, in these two examples, the famous French partitive article, which is otherwise used when saying, for instance, **Tu as du vin? Non, je n'en ai plus.**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here *des* is, as you've said, the equivalent for the English zero article.

Indeed *des* here is an indefinite article and is the plural form of *un*

> *un oiseau* → a bird ⟹ *des oiseaux* → birds

Comment: thx indoxica for the corrections I am a little tired :)

Comment: Avec plaisir. You're welcome.